# Laravel queue:work is processing 10000 in 60s until it crashes

Tags: laravel, redis, laravel-queue

I don't know what exactly happened but when ever I start:

```
php artisan queue:work & redis-server.exe (windows)
```

I get a lot of processings for 1 event even tho app is not used (opened on browser)

[image]

I am not even using this Event from picture....

I am so unsure why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well using `redis-cli flushall` and `queue:work --tries=1` helped me clean all proceses that were stored within redis and fail after one try.